# Using Wordpress for installing Civi got these errors!

Tags: wordpress

Notice: Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in /home/yonatony/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 127

Notice: Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in /home/yonatony/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 104

Notice: Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in /home/yonatony/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 105

Notice: Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in /home/yonatony/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 104

Notice: Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in /home/yonatony/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 105

Fatal error: Class 'CRM_Core_Config' not found in /home/yonatony/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/install/index.php on line 138

Comment: Please update your task with CiviCRM version and wordpress version you are trying to install on. That helps understanding the issue more.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure all files of civicrm were uploaded in your site files and file `wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php` is present there.

Also make sure your database credentials are correct and following lines are present in the end of file civicrm.settings.php

`require_once 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
CRM_Core_ClassLoader::singleton()->register();`